# Telegram bot: wait for a message in a channel, edit it, and redirect to another channel

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I need to create a telegram bot, using PHP, that get every message that arrive on a channel where **I'm included (but i'm not the admin)**. Then send a message to a page on my server: `www.example.com/edit-message.php` to manipulate it with regex and others check. (I think this page need to be set as webhook?). Then message modified is sent automatically inside an **own channel (where I am the admin)**.

I find poor tutorial in PHP for bots, and nothing referred to "get message from a channel not mine automatically".

Also i don't understand how it works: how to detect new message from a (not mine) channel without polling / checking status every X seconds!

Anyone can help me to understand steps I needs? not the code, but some tips or functions in PHP if they exist already for my goal.

Actually i'm using commercial bot to do this job, but i'd like to create my own cause this one used actually is not very cheap and my follower are not much actually... :(

Comment: You can use telegram to create a bot working as a hook. Then your hook will be called when an event rises. Simple as that.

Comment: @MarkusZeller ok but my question is: how to "intercept" updates from channel not mine? what is the function I need to search in docs API? i've read a lot of disappoint about this....but i know it is possible cause the commercial bot i'm using do it.

Comment: Not at all. This is called security. Bots should only react when explicitly called.

Comment: @MarkusZeller ok. so could you address me to a starting docs to "wakeup" my bot when this type of event occur (new message from a channel not owned)

Comment: You can't. And that is good, because any invited bot could store all encrypted messages and make them public.

Comment: @MarkusZeller so... commercial bots how did this magic?

Comment: AFAIK there are some bots that can read all messages, _if_ they have admin rights

Comment: @Qw3ry yes, if they are admin on a channel yes.... but in this case not. I'm a guest of a channel and with this commercial bot name CONFLUXBOT  (also there is a free version limited to 10 forward message) I can forward message from a channel not mine to another channel (mine)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/). It's Python instead of PHP but it can do exactly what you want.

First, configure your session and do some setups. Afterwards, you need something like this:

```py
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler


def my_function(client, message):
    # as_copy parameter for forward message without header
    message.forward("your_channel", as_copy=True)


app = Client("my_account")

my_handler = MessageHandler(my_function, filters.chat("channel_id"))
app.add_handler(my_handler)

app.run()
```